# float main tables/figures after main text THEN add appendix and appendix tables

Tags: page-numbering, appendices, elsarticle, endfloat

I'm struggling with `\usepackage{endfloat}`, `\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}`, and the appendix.

**What I want:**

I want the main text, followed by tables and figures inserted/cited in the main text (floated to the *end of the main document only*), and then I want the appendix with its tables exactly where specified. I want the main text tables to be numbered 1, 2, ..., T. I want the appendix tables to be numbered A1, A2, ..., A.

I'd also like the main document through the end floated tables to be numbered 1, 2, ..., P. Then I want the appendix to start over with roman numerals.

**Here's what I tried:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[notablist]{endfloat}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\rhead{My short title \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% get rid of footer included in elsarticle
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

% appendix page numbering
\let\origappendix\appendix % save the existing appendix command
\renewcommand\appendix{\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}\origappendix}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{My long title}

\author[add1]{Me\corref{cor1}}
\ead{me@email.com}
\author[add1]{You}
\ead{you@email.com}

\cortext[cor1]{Please address correspondence to me}
\address[add1]{Address}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
  \end{abstract}
  \begin{keyword}
    Keywords
  \end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

My text page 1

\newpage
My text page 2 and Table \ref{tab}.

\newpage
My page 3

\newpage

\begin{table}
\centerline{\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{My table}
  \label{tab}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
 Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
  \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item My note
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}

\thispagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\efloat@restorefloats
\makeatother
\setcounter{figure}{0} % Start again
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{table}{0} % Start again
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{table}}

\appendix

My appendix and Table \ref{apptab}. I want the appendix to appear after Table \ref{tab} which should be floated to the end of the main document. 

In other words, I want the main text, followed by tables and figures inserted in the main text (floated to the end), and then I want the appendix with its tables exactly where specified. 

\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Table should be in appendix}
  \label{apptab}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
 Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
  \midrule
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  10 & 11 & 12 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item My note
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i would assume that the `endfloat` package would do the job.  get your floats from the main body of the doc by using `\processdelayedfloats` _before_ `\appendix`; process those that appear in the appendix in the normal way for end of document.

Comment: @wasteofspace -- didn't find any obvious duplicate, so please make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From @wasteofspace:

> i would assume that the `endfloat` package would do the job. get your floats from the main body of the doc by using `\processdelayedfloats` before `\appendix`; process those that appear in the appendix in the normal way for end of document.

This worked for me.